# Docker recovery of container running overlay2

Tags: docker

I host a minecraft server for my partner and her friends. The server died in an unexpected way, the processor failed. I'm able to recover the files from the device.

I have:

- lib\docker\containers\
- lib\docker\volumes: Which has nothing, its all in overlay2 unforunately.
- lib\docker\overlay2\

There are a few corrupt files in the overlay 2 folder, but looking at the diffs it doesn't look like it impacts the folders I care about.

Is there any way to restore the filesystem within the container, repairing/ignoring the broken diffs in overlay2?

The files I need are in the overlay2, not in the volumes.

```
docker start fa34565a2f40
Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /mnt/d0/Restore/container-station-data/lib/docker/overlay2/dcf914587eef741b9193ab6cad367d50365fdbc3b889e75b3f9afac98cc93bab/merged: no such file or directory
Error: failed to start containers: fa34565a2f40
```

```
docker inspect fa34565a2f40
[]
Error response from daemon: readlink /mnt/d0/Restore/container-station-data/lib/docker/overlay2/l/TZMO3DORTK3IM3I26WKZ7CX4RX: no such file or directory
```

Comment: I'd just delete the entire `/var/lib/docker` tree (maybe saving the `volumes` subdirectory).  You won't lose anything that wouldn't have been lost when the container exited even if there hadn't been a system failure.

Comment: Unforunately, all the files I need are contained in overlay2 :(.
I used the defaults of a GUI based docker tool, it didn't create volumes for the ubuntu image (it does for many images though, just not that one).